# CSRF Origin check failed Django/Vue.JS

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, csrf

I am currently making a web app that uses Vue.JS for the frontend part and Django for the backend. I'm using django-rest-framework to communicate between the client and the server.

I would like to specify that everything works fine when using *Postman* for testing my requests

When trying to login or register (those are only the two features I have implemented yet) The server sends back the following response:

> "CSRF Failed: Origin checking failed - http://localhost:8080 does not match any trusted origins." Status: 403

The csrftoken cookie is there and I made sure it's sent

**Here are some details on my setup**

Requests are sent using Axios. In `main.js` I overrode the following `axios.defaults`

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

And the login request is sent in this method in a *Pinia* user store:

```
async login(email, password)
{
    try
    {
        let response = await axios.post('authentication/login/', {email: email, password:  
        password});
        this.setUserData(response.data.id, response.data.email);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
            
},
```

Server side:

My User view is written the following way:

```
def UserAuthenticationView(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        #retrieve currently logged-in user
        pass

    def post(self, request):
        #register new user in database
        pass

    @api_view(['POST])
    def login(request):
        # decode request sent as json
        body = json.loads(request.body)

        # make sure all fields are present
        try:
            email = body['email']
            password = body['password']
        except KeyError:
            return Response("Email or password are missing", status=400)

        # validateEmail() and validatePassword() are custom functions that check the format of both 
        # fields
        if (not validateEmail(email) or not validatePassword(password)):
            return Response("Email or password are missing", status=400)

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        # check if authentication worked        
        if user is None:
            return Response("Failed to authenticate user", status=400)
        else:
            # log user on session and return it
            login(request, user)
            return Response(UserAuthenticationView.serializer_class(user).data)
```

Inside `settings.py` I added the following line

`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:8080"]`

But because my login view needs to access the body of the request I get an internal server error. From what I understand, the CSRF Middleware reads the body of the request first and I should use `csrf_exempt()` to prevent this behaviour

So in `urls.py` I tried the following with no success:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.UserAuthenticationView.as_view()),
    path('login/', csrf_exempt(views.UserAuthenticationView.login)),
```

What I don't understand either is that APIView is supposed to automatically csrf_exempt all views inside it but my register view, which corresponds to the `post()` method of UserAuthenticationView doesn't work for the same reason.

Comment: Does anything change if you change `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` to `['https://*', 'http://*']` ?. This is not good practice, but if you still get the same error it may be a fault in the axios-defaults.

Comment: It did not change anything. I followed your recommendations and looked if it wasn't axios. I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022218/axios-post-fails-with-403-csrf-token-validation-failed-but-works-fine-in-postman which states that axios doesn't include the "Cookie" header by default but when I check my request's header it does. If I include the header manually it doesn't do anything

Comment: Sorry to hear this, but I'll be unable to help you any further as my knowledge of axios is very limited.
I hope someone with more knowledge will provide a suitable answer.